# Mvc Authorize attribute is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, authorize-attribute

I have created `HomeController` decorated with `AuthorizeAttribute`, and also created `AccountController`, but it is not redirecting to the `Login()` action of `AccountController`.

Home controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Account controller:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LogOnCustom log)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(Membership.ValidateUser(log.UserName,log.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(log.UserName, log.Isremeber);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "logOn error");
            }
        }
        return View(log);
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" >
    </forms>
</authentication>
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had this same problem.  Check your web.config and see if it contains this line:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Remove the "`<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />`" line and it should start working. When the FormsAuthentication module is removed, there is no code listening for the 401 event so it doesn't have a chance to redirect the user to the login page.