# Creating dynamic tables using C#

Tags: c#

I have a user table which contains the details about the users registered .
I need to display a report  which shows how many users registered in each month for each vendor. I am using the following lambda to retrieve the data. After retrieving the data, i am again looping through one more list and assigning the lender names to the previous list.

```
var list = dbContext.Users.ToList()
            .Where(u => u.CreatedOn > DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12))
            .GroupBy(u => new { u.CreatedOn.Value.Month, u.LenderId })
    .Select(u => new UserData
    {
        UserCount = u.Count(),
        Month = u.FirstOrDefault().CreatedOn.Value.Month.ToString(),
        MonthName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(u.FirstOrDefault().CreatedOn.Value.Month),
        LanderId = u.FirstOrDefault().LenderId
    }).ToList();
        var lenderList = dbContext.Lenders.ToList();
        foreach (UserData ud in list)
        {
            foreach (Lendersr lp in lenderList)
            {
                if (lp.Id == ud.LenderId)
                {
                    ud.LenderName = lp.Name;
                }
                if(ud.LanderId == null)
                {
                    ud.LenderName = "ABC";
                }
            }
    }
```

Now I have the list of data in the following format

[List of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJn1S.png)

And each row in the list is having the following format.
[Data in each row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8gki.png)

Now I need to generate a table dynamically in the following format to show the report.

[Report to be shown in the following format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTU7H.png)

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mvc Authorize attribute is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054129/mvc-authorize-attribute-is-not-working)